# Updating UI from Backgroundworker Thread (Invoke)

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I'm currently trying to update my control (`Label.Text`) from my `BackgroundWorker` thread.

```cs
Control1 mycontrol = new Control1();

mycontrol.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { mycontrol.statusmainlabel.Text = "Setting up"; });
```

But I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called for control until the window handle is created."

I'm trying to update my `UserControl` from my other class that is called by the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Without a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure how _your_ code should be fixed. However, see duplicates for general advice to lead you to better comprehension of the clearly-worded error message and strategies for fixing it. As for the code you did post, if you are literally creating a `Control1` object for the sole purpose of calling `Invoke()`, that's wrong. You need to use a control instance that already exists in your form.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your control to an exist container control which has been shown.

For example:

```
Control1 mycontrol = new Control1();
form1.Controls.Add(mycontrol);
//then update it
```

Comment: It is more likely that the OP should not be creating the new control in the first place. In any case, it's not possible to know what the answer is given the lack of a [mcve].